# Nongreedy regex matcher not working

Tags: regex

I have the following test to parse via regex

```
{id=ID, catalogId=A2A01, marketingCode=CODE, productId=PRODUCT_ID, sku=SKUINFO}
```

I am using the following Regex pattern

```
(?<=marketingCode=)(.*)(?=, )
```

However is matching

```
CODE, productId=PRODUCT_ID
```

How do I make it just match

```
CODE
```

Comment: `.*` **is**  greedy. It's not non-greedy as you mentioned. Change it to `.*?`.

Comment: It's not non-greedy. Change `(?<=marketingCode=)(.*)(?=, )` to `(?<=marketingCode=)(.*?)(?=, )`.

Comment: You can use: `(?<=marketingCode=)([^,]*)(?=,)` See this demo: https://regex101.com/r/kPs5DK/1